# Soundcloud https auth with Chrome

Tags: javascript, authentication, https, soundcloud

My app's auth page uses https and I have the soundcloud connect js using https:

```
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
```

However when a user has logged in through the pop-up Google Chrome will block the callback that closes the window and complains that:

```
The page at ... ran insecure content from http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js.
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try maybe:
`<script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>`

However this got some performance issues in IE7, IE8 according to this post:
http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/18/css-files-downloaded-twice-in-internet-explorer-with-protocol-relative-urls/

**Update after comment**
After looking on your link:

```
 <div ng-controller="LoginCtrl" ng-init="init('numbers', 
   'http://distinctive-kreek.rhcloud.com/authenticated')">
 <h1> Login ...</h1>
 </div>
```

Isn't that the problem that here is http used?

Comment: Hey, ya I tried a relative protocol before and got the same error (and would like to avoid that issue) - thanks :)

Comment: Doh, good catch, however the problem is still happening. The redirect actually doesn't need to be https but OpenShift (rhcloud) have a bug where everything is being redirected to https at the moment https://openshift.redhat.com/community/forums/openshift/my-site-runs-through-https-exclusively

Comment: Added a CNAME on top of the openshift URL and it no longer redirects to https